# Get user products with using user_id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hey guys I'm making a website in codeigniter and I'm trying to make the page for another user profile. On the profile of another user I want to show all the products that that user uploaded. I tried to do it like the same as you're own user profile but with that I'm using the session user_id.

This is what I have right now:

Controller function:

```
public function userdetails($user_id)
 {
  //load the model
  $this->load->model('User_model');


  $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->User_model->getdata($user_id);
  $data['products'] = $this->User_model->userproducts();
  $this->load->view('profiel_user',$data);

 }
```

function in model:

```
public function userproducts($user_id)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
       return $query->result_array();
    }
    return array();
}
```

So when I'm on a user profile page, I want to show all the products that belong to the profile user_id I clicked on.

I also have this function already to get the user_id of that profile page I'm on:

```
function getdata($user_id){
  $this->db->select("*"); 
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
```

Anyone got model code of how I can do it?
thanks

database information:

Table 1 : products:

```
product_id
product_naam
product_beschrijving
user_id
ophaal_plaats
product_foto
product_foto_thumb
date_created
date_updated
category_id

table 2 : users:

user_id
email
voornaam
achternaam
beschrijving
profiel_foto
```

Comment: How can I make get products function that have same user_id ?

Comment: you had logged in and you want product from another user profile..right?

Comment: Yes I need a model function, so when I click on another user profile, it shows all his products with the same user_id. So all his products that have the same user_id in products table and in users table.

Comment: So maybe instead of this query:  $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products");  u can show me a query how I can get all the products with the same user_id?

Comment: @Learningprogrammingphp44 Please check my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your function as below

```
function getdata($user_id){
  $this->db->select("products.*,users.*"); 
  $this->db->from('products');
  $this->db->join('users','users.user_id = products.user_id','left');
  $this->db->where('users.user_id', $user_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: But I also need to do something like this right in controller?: $data['products'] = $this->User_model->userproducts();

Comment: Look I change my question and show you what I have right now ok

Comment: @Learningprogrammingphp44 Please have a look at my answer now. By the way, you don't need `users.*` as far as I think.

Comment: And what do I need to do in controller?

Comment: Getting this error: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1052

Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous

SELECT `users`.*, `products`.* FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `products` ON `products`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` WHERE `user_id` IS NULL

Filename: models/User_model.php

Line Number: 24

Comment: @Learningprogrammingphp44 Please check now

Comment: Now when I try to echo a product it shows this: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: products

Filename: views/profiel_user.php

Line Number: 54

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/profiel_user.php
Line: 54
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/User.php
Line: 32
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159042/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-learningprogrammingphp44).

Comment: Hello sir, I still had one more question, it only shows 1 product that the user uploaded, not all the products. Do you know why maybe?

Comment: because of where condition, we are only selecting the products which were added by the current user

Comment: Yes iknow. But the current user uploaded a total of 7 products. And it only shows the first product that he uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Create a similar function like this

```
public function product_other_user_id($user_id)
      {
          $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
          return $this->db->get('products')->result();
      }
```

then in your controller call that function after you have user_id for example

```
$userProducts = product_other_user_id($user_id);
```

When you return combine both user and their products in an array or an associate array whatever you feel comfortable with.